# crear variable javascript desde php con Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Deseo crear una variable javascript desde php que esta dentro de la onreadystatechange = function() del objeto XMLHttpRequest() de Ajax.

Esto o tengo en Ready() de mi javascript:

```
  function respuestaAjax(str) {
    if (str.length == 0) {
      document.getElementsByName("categorias")[0].innerHTML = "";
      return;
    } else {
      var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.open("GET", "../../php/respuesta-select-cuenta.php?q="+str, true);
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          document.getElementsByName("categorias")[0].innerHTML += this.responseText;
        }
      };
      xmlhttp.send();
    }
  } 

 

  <?php    
$q = $_REQUEST["q"];
  

  $varJavascript =  "<Script>var cuenta = []; ";

    $varJavascript .= "cuenta.push('".$q."');";

 
  echo $varJavascript."</Script>"; ?>
```

El problema es que aunque creo la variable javascript y le cargo un dato, después javascript no ve esta variable como propia para usarla en el programa y me dice que no esta definida. ¿que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 0):

Para empezar te digo, esto no es una buena práctica, deberías tener js y php separados, es decir, deberías cambiar la lógica de como intercambias la información en tu código.

Probá lo siguiente:

```
function respuestaAjax(str) {
    if (str.length == 0) {
      document.getElementsByName("categorias")[0].innerHTML = "";
      return;
    } else {
      var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.open("GET", "../../php/respuesta-select-cuenta.php?q="+str, true);
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    const myArray = JSON.parse(<?php echo "'[".$_REQUEST["q"]."]'"; ?>);
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          document.getElementsByName("categorias")[0].innerHTML += this.responseText;
        }
      };
      xmlhttp.send();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias pero no funciona. No entendí muy bien su explicación pero yo tengo el js en un archivo.js y el php en un archivo.php separadamente. Una idea. Yo cuando hago exactamente lo mismo sin ajax y cargo la variable js con php tras el ready funciona bien pero por ajax no.

Comment: No entendí la pregunta y es lo que logré responder, aun con lo que decis aquí sigue siento difícil para mí entender lo que necesitas. Sería bueno que organizaras tu pensamiento y redactes de nuevo tu necesidad.

Comment: Tienes toda razón. Ignora mi código por favor, basicamente lo que deseo es pintar una variable array javascript obtenida desde php a traves de ajax. Si tienes un ejemplo me vale. Deseo pintar algo como var array = []; array.push('tomate'); array.push('naranja'); y que despues javascript la vea como variable válida. Esto desde php directamente y tras cargar la pagina funciona, pero desde php->ajax->pagina (javascript) no funciona.

Comment: Cuando miro en la consola me dice esto de la variable: Uncaught ReferenceError: cuenta is not defined
    <anonymous> debugger eval code:1

Comment: Mira, lo que podes hacer es imprimir una cadena de texto conteniendo la estructura de un array por ejemplo: ["hola"] y luego convertirlo a objeto usando JSON. El ejemplo que te di debería de funcionar.

Comment: Ya he dado con la solución. Mi inexperiencia con Ajax me ha jugado una mala pasada. Tan solo desde php paso la cadena con echo y después en el archivo.js con la recuperación de Ajax como es javascript tan solo tengo que poner una variable global y añadir con push la cadena recibida desde php y listo ya funciona. Mil perdón de corazón son las cosas de los novatos. Gracias Edwin Munguia.